# Fighting In The Highest Of Heels (chopines)

Tags: internal-consistency, combat, clothing

Assuming a combatant who has trained for some years with these shoes and assuming weaponry in terms of a one handed sword or perhaps a spear or one of the shorter, lighter polearms, how plausible would it be for them to fight while wearing these? (assuming mainly one on one duels or scuffs with only a small number of people)

[image: a pair of chopines]

- A pair of chopines

By plausible I mean, would the shoes prove such a detriment as to render the wearer ineffective? Would there be any benefits to wearing such shoes? Assume mostly realistic (even if pushing the outer limits) human ability.

Comment: I bet a Brazilian fitness model would do just fine fighting with those heels on.

Comment: You mean this particular shoe style, no heel counters, no shoelaces, no ankle support?

Comment: its more a handicap in my opinion, but you still can fight while wearing it considering some japan swordsman wear getta in their duel, which look similar to that. though it probably have a lot of problem regarding footwork and swiftness, and also increase your height, so its harder to aim at your head and neck, but... your leg or lower body is harder to defend and to attack since now your attack direction is limited if fighting with non chopines opponent, but if it against same heels i dont see much problem since both is in handicap and almost in similar height.

Comment: this is just my opinion not backed by anything, but  i think the sword need to be very sharp or no armor, otherwise upon impact they may get pushed and losing their balance, but looking at the wideness it may help giving better grip though, but as i say it probably harder to make a swift footwork such as slit or lunge attack doesnt seems like a possible move for that. though no ankle support help to make tip toe kind of stance at least that can help in giving burst force and tricking the distance or height but on the other hand that chopines is not flat but tilt or angle or raise a bit so.....

Comment: Ninja threw spikes everywhere. High heel: "really, that's all you got!"

Comment: to help what i mean (since i have trouble to find a good english term for it out of my head) when you tip toe with that kind of angle, its like how slide is, and stressing on your toe, it may make the chopines slip due to the force, but again looking at the wide elephant kind of foot base, it may help better grip to prevent that, but it still gonna be stressing on your toe and maybe the tendon too, and i think it wont give more burst force due to the smaller gap or surface when you start to stomp.

Comment: also i think 2hand weapon especially sword is better fit for this rather than one hand sword, because one hand sword need more dodging (if no shield or buckler) and footwork compare to 2hand sword in my opinion.

Comment: @user6760 throw bolas then, or just throw the spikes at opponent face, or use the chain sickle to tangle the high heel.

Answer (score 4):

**Sure!**

Fundamentally no different than stilts, and if Conan Lee can [do it with spectacular style](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jqsPOO5IY3Q), I don't see why ancient Venetians couldn't duel in chopines.

[Not all chopines are alike](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PWOs2RO-Xwo). Combat chopines will likely be designed to increase stability and also address the issues of falling off that clog type footwear comes with. Some kind of laces or straps or even a full boot will likely be supplied. Perhaps even a split chopine with some kind of hinge that would allow the foot to flex.

Answer (score 1):

Much worse weaponry and armor has been tried in combat, and worked to some extent. While it has a fair few obvious downsides, it's not unthinkable that someone would try these in battle after extensive training.

The main benefit of this would be the higher attack position (obviously) and extended reach, at the cost of reduced mobility and balance. I say reduced mobility because you wouldn't be able to jolt around like a boxer in the ring, but you would be able to move quicker in a straight line to close in on your opponent.

As for weaponry the most obvious choice would be the pole arm for the extended reach, but weapons like these are based on stabbing motions which require solid balance. Your opponent grabbing and pulling/pushing this weapon would instantly destabilise you and the fight would be over. A better choice would be an overhead weapon like a mace, morning star, or hammer, maximising the benefit of your higher position. Combined with a small shield for defence, and some shin guards to protect the more exposed legs, this could possibly make an effective fighter.

A realistic application for this could be in battles where horses aren't an option. The heightened position would reduce the risk of attacks to the head, negating he need for large helmets. This widened view, combined with the higher position, could help officers get a better oversight of the battlefield while still remaining mobile.

Comment: i am not sure it move quicker in a straight line, since this definitely cant do horizontal slide or lunge for example nor step aside swiftly but need a wide arc to do so without stumble, or lift  the leg until one of the heel dont touch the surface, seems quite straining to me. also shield or armor probably can  disturb the balance upon impact in my opinion. if we talking about high heel but not chopines type it did use by cavalry at least, also if we talking about battlefield rather than duel they are pretty much will be devastated by range weapon though especially against flying stone.

Comment: and i also think they will easily getting tripped or hook or drag down by halberd or polearms weapon too, if we talking about battlefield or duels against opponent that not use this heel, and when they falling down or losing balance they can easily get pin down, if this heel still attached to their foot or leg, since its probably harder to stand up.

Comment: @LiJun I agree with your concerns, and I meant to make clear this is definitely not the best choice in any situation. I mostly covered this with my "fair few obvious downsides" and "worse has been used" remarks, and chose to highlight any possible benefits for the sake of this answer. But by all means I would never advise using this in any situation.

Comment: A higher position that leaves you completely exposed is actually a detriment in combat. And it is really easy to get a head injury on stilts all they have to do is knock over the horribly top heavy fighter and gravity will do the rest. the officer thing is the only real advantage.